# Python replace only part of a re.sub match

Tags: python, regex, match

The following Python script: `re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]pi[^a-zA-Z]", "(math.pi)", "2pi3 + supirse")`

results in: `'(math.pi) + supirse'`

While the match of a non-alpha before and after `pi` is critical, I do not want these non-alpha characters to be replaced in the match. I would like to see the following output: `'2(math.pi)3 + supirse'`

Note: A previous suggestion of the following: `re.sub("\Bpi\B", "(math.pi)", "2pi3 + supirse")`

results in a complete replacement of every instance: `'2(math.pi)3 + su(math.pi)rse'` which is also NOT what I am looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this instead: `re.sub("(?<=[^a-zA-Z])pi(?=[^a-zA-Z])", "(math.pi)", "2pi3 + supirse")`

Visualization: http://regex101.com/r/fX5wX3

Comment: This link to regex101 is a really useful one! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use lookahead/lookbehind:

```
import re

print re.sub("(?<=[^a-zA-Z])pi(?=[^a-zA-Z])", "(math.pi)", "2pi3 + supirse")
```

See here for the concrete produced result: http://ideone.com/rSd8H

Answer (score 0):

In fact you need a lowercase `"\b"` that means *word boundary*, while `"\B"` means *not a word boundary*.

Try this:

```
import re
re.sub(r"\bpi\b", "(math.pi)", "2pi3 + supirse")
```

That would yield `'2pi3 + supirse'`